# Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid icc profile: bad sequence number

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I'm trying to read a JPG in order to resize it but sometimes, when I try to do :

```
ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("R:/temp/test.jpg"));
```

I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid icc profile: bad sequence number
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:560)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:315)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:437)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:553)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:931)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:915)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)
```

I don't know exactly why sometimes it works, sometimes it fails. It is probably coming from the JPG itself but how I can resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of java are you using ? There seems to be a bug in Java 1.5 as discussed here - http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6791502